# Перенос строки после запятой

Tags: php, строки

Есть строка:

```
 0.00,0.00
```

Как сделать, чтобы запись после запятой была с новой строки?

Comment: replace() запятой на (запятая+перевод строки).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = '0.00,0.00';
$str = str_replace(',', "\r\n", $str);
echo $str; // Перенос строки
echo nl2br($str); // Для html
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так будет понятнееееееееее:

```
<?php
$test = 'a,b,c,d';
echo $test . PHP_EOL;
$test2 = str_replace(',',",\n", $test);
echo $test2;
```

Comment: Минусующим балбесам хочу сказать, что моё решение правильное -- и вставляет ИМЕННО запятую и перенос, как просил автор вопроса. Заплюсованное решение запятую не выводит!